# Having trouble setting up localhost on mac

Tags: mysql, macos, macos-catalina, macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to set up localhost on my Mac, which runs on Catalina.

I followed instructions here:
https://websitebeaver.com/set-up-localhost-on-macos-high-sierra-apache-mysql-and-php-7-with-sslhttps

And got stuck here:

[image]

Instead, I'm seeing:

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
> 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
> /Users/nana/Sites/index.php on line 2
>
> Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
> /Users/nana/Sites/index.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object()
> on bool in /Users/nana/Sites/index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
> in /Users/bkwon/Sites/index.php on line 3

Now, I realize that the article is for High Sierra, not Catalina. I wonder if that's why I'm seeing the error message? I'm not familiar with this at all, I just followed the instructions in the article while having no idea what I'm doing, so would be thankful if you could be a bit more specific in giving answers.

Note: I tried a new plain number (e.g. 12345) password for MySQL, but that didn't do anything

Comment: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` means that the username, password, or accesspoint for the user you are trying to connect to your mysql instance is wrong. Can you connect directly to your mysql instance? If so, you should check that all those details are correct.

Comment: I re-set those and was able to get past that 23 item. Is this article supposed to work for Catalina too though? b/c I finished all the steps and you're supposed to see a padlock next to the url at the end, but i'm not seeing it

Comment: What's the url you're going to? Does it start with `https://`?

Comment: Ok i just realized the article says "go to https://localhost in your browser" --> I'm seeing This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED      Is this not supposed to work for Catalina? I completed every step without any problem.   just typing 'localhost' (without http) gets me to "MySQL works perfectly!" page

Comment: Try this, go to your mac's hosts file and make sure it has this line in it `127.0.0.1       localhost`, if it doesnt, add it, then edit it to be like `127.0.0.1  localhost  testsite.com` (note you can use any value you want for "testsite". Then try to go to `https://testsite.com` and see if it works.

Comment: What is  "mac's host file" exactly?

Comment: See this tutorial https://setapp.com/how-to/edit-mac-hosts-file

Comment: it does have ##
127.0.0.1       localhost   :(

Comment: please edit that line as described above

Comment: thanks but typing https://testsite.com didn't work :/

Comment: Also, remove the `##` in front of that line

Comment: Did you follow the directions in that tutorial for changing that file? Its a protected file so editing it takes specific steps

Comment: removed ##, https://testsite.com still didn't work

Comment: i didn't follow instructions but i saved it (control + O) and existed it, and when i go back to  terminal, the changes are made and i see testsite.com

Comment: i just did 'In Terminal, type sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder', so i actually followed the instructions. the site still not working. could this be b/c mine's Catalina?

Comment: this is what i see now: ##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.

127.0.0.1       localhost testsite.com
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

Comment: weird - now entering "localhost" (without https) doesn't work anymore. says This site can’t be reached

Comment: Because it seams you are very inexperienced in this, I would recommend to use MAMP to setup HTML, PHP and mySQL server on your Mac

Comment: thank you https://tech-cookbook.com/2019/10/07/setting-up-your-local-server-on-macos-catalina-2019-mamp/ this article mentions MAMP, but i'm stuck in the first step b/c "localhost" is now not working anymore. can i easily fix this?

Comment: https://www.mamp.info/en/mac/ I mean this software bundle. It will help you much

Comment: ah thank you. is this for wordpress sites only, though? mine's just a simple jquery css html website

Comment: No this is just a wrapper to easily install and configure httpd, php and MySQL and some more

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff I was able to using MAMP.  Thanks